# Grabbing data from get request query node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, query-string

I am making fake image request.

**client side**

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.width = 1;
image.height = 1;
image.src = "http://localhost:8080/server/?currentVisitTimestamp%3D1369293177%26lastVisitTimestamp%3D1369293137" //enocded
```

Request status is `200`

**server side**
I am using express framework

```
   app.get('/server',function(request,response){
    console.log(request.query);
    response.send();
   });
```

console log prints as below:

```
{ 'currentVisitTimestamp=1369293177&lastVisitTimestamp=1369293137': '' }
```

output expected is smething like this

```
       'currentVisitTimestamp=1369293177&lastVisitTimestamp=1369293137'
```

why its constructing as key-value pair?

Comment: I think this is what you need http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.originalUrl

Comment: Fix: var url =  request.originalUrl;
     var queryString = url.substring(url.indexOf('?')+1, url.length);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented in [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query),

`req.query`

`This property is an object containing the parsed query-string, defaulting to {}.`

As [elclanrs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670396/elclanrs) mentioned in comment you could use [`req.originalUrl`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.originalUrl) to get what you want.

It would be something like this:

```
var queryString = req.originalUrl.replace('/server?', '');
//queryString === 'currentVisitTimestamp=1369293177&lastVisitTimestamp=1369293137' ==> true
```

Comment: Thanks. var queryString = req.originalUrl.replace('/server/?', ''); it fixes.